# c++: Eigen Library newbie sort

Tags: c++, sorting, eigen

I can't for the life of me work out why this isn't working correctly. It doesn't seem to return the kth element.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> matrix;

double test(matrix& D, int k)
{
    auto d = D.row(1);
    std::nth_element(d.data(),d.data()+k, d.data()+d.size());
    return d(k) ;
}
```

I have also tried

```
template <typename ScalarType, typename Derived>
void Sort(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &xValues)
{
std::sort(xValues.derived().data(), xValues.derived().data()+xValues.derived().size());
}


double test(matrix& D, int k)
{
    auto d = D.row(1);
    Sort<double>(d);
    return d(k) ;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:-

I have just tried changing

```
auto d = D.row(1);
```

to

```
Eigen::VectorXd rowD = D.row(1);
....
```

and it seems to work ok.

Slightly confused by that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eigen matrices are [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) per default.  That means, that a row of a matrix is not a contiguous C array and you cannot use the data pointer as an iterator.

For example, a 3x4 matrix would be stored as:

```
0 3 6  9
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
```

Now, `row(1)` would be

```
1 4 7 10
```

But the pointer iterator you are passing to `nth_element()` will access

```
1 2 3 4
```

Your code works if you change your `matrix` typedef to row-major:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> matrix;
```

---

**Update:** Your edited example works since you *copy* the row to a vector.  For vectors (one-dimensional matrices), it does not matter if the data is stored row-major or column-major.