# How sort unique on a std::vector of Eigen::Vector?

Tags: c++, eigen

The compiler can't figure out the less than operator for the type. I've also tried with a lambda and predicate function.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
typedef Eigen::Vector3f vec3;

inline bool operator<(const vec3 &lhs, const vec3 &rhs) {
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() && lhs.y() < rhs.y() && lhs.z() < rhs.z();
}

inline bool cmpVecs(const vec3 &lhs, const vec3 &rhs) {
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() && lhs.y() < rhs.y() && lhs.z() < rhs.z();
}


inline void removeDuplicates(std::vector<vec3> &con)
{
    std::sort(con.data(), con.data() + con.size());
    auto itr = std::unique(con.begin(), con.end(), cmpVecs);
    con.resize(itr - con.begin());
}

void init(std::vector<vec3> &verts) {
    removeDuplicates(verts);
}
```

VS 2012 error:

> algorithm(3618): error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which
>   takes a left-hand operand of type 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols>'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion) 1>          with 1>          [
>   1>              _Scalar=float, 1>              _Rows=3, 1>
>   _Cols=1 1>          ]

Related Posts:

- [c++: Eigen Library newbie sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140746/c-eigen-library-newbie-sort)

Comment: Your comparison functions are incorrect, as `std::sort` require a strict weak ordering predicate. `{
   if (lhs.x() < rhs.x())
      return true;
   if (rhs.x() < lhs.x())
      return false;

   if (lhs.y() < rhs.y())
      return true;
   if (rhs.y() < lhs.y())
      return false;

   return lhs.z() < rhs.z();
}`

Comment: The comparison in the comment above works for me. This was quite difficult to find, despite that unique is very common in matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::sort` has an override available which allows you to specify which comparator you want to use, for example:

```
struct vec3comp{
    bool operator()(const vec3 &lhs, const vec3 &rhs){
        return lhs.x() < rhs.x() && lhs.y() < rhs.y() && lhs.z() < rhs.z();
    }
} mycomp;

std::sort(con.data(), con.data() + con.size(),mycomp);`
```

Edit: can you show your code with a lambda function? It should work fine.

Comment: TBH, my sort method isn't correct either I don't think. I think it's sorting per float instead of per 3. I just copied the link I posted above. It's also possible that it isn't byte aligned... checking that now.

Comment: Yea, static_assert fails on testing size == 3*sizeof(float), which makes sense in some ways, albeit bad. Either way it's giving me the error with operator< even when using the struct method you linked, though it should be written mycomp().

Comment: nvm i was doing sizeof(sizeof())... so like i said. Still gives me the error even when trying the struct.

Comment: Turns out I just wasn't using the compare function with std::sort(). I was only using it with unique. I would upvote but I don't have the ability.

Comment: Just mark the answer and it's more than ok. That way the (answered) question won't remain on top of the pages.